# Android - How to detect if the incoming call is redirected?

Tags: android, redirect, call, forward

After googling I successfully get the `incoming_number` when there is an incoming call.
But I still cannot find how to detect if the call is forwarded(redirected).

Is there some flag or something ?

Best Regards,
Ivan

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

For an understanding.

When a call is redirected to a different number before it is answered is referred as “Call Forward”.

Forwarded calls do not not carry any data with them.

From what I understood, you can actually create a broadcast receiver

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public static String numberToCall;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("CallRecorder", "CallBroadcastReceiver::onReceive got Intent: " + intent.toString());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        numberToCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "CallBroadcastReceiver intent has EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER: " + numberToCall);
    }

}
}
```

Since you have the incoming number, you can actually do a workaround, determining that to where the incoming number was forwarded "as an outgoing call"

Comment: this is an intent for `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` my question regards to an incoming call

Comment: A call is incoming if it comes on our cell phone, and if that particular call is forwarded or redirected then it becomes an outgoing call. Keeping this behaviour in mind, we can determine the outgoing call.

Comment: I see your logic but still dont understand, lemme test the code now

Comment: I tested your code and there is no instance when it runs.

Comment: Funny I never found a solution. If you are using samsung, when the call is forwarded, a toast appears for a second when the call is received. That means it is possible to read if a call is forwarded. If you see this and have a solution please answer.